# Click Event Not Updating Page At Right Time (No JQuery)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JavaScript. I can't use JQuery

The thing is, i have a table and i want to highlight the selected row on the `click` event, and at the same time i have to change the value of an input field, but for some reason when i first click the row the highlight effect gets stuck on that row and also the value of the `input` only changes after I click a different row. It's really weird.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n32d72ve/4/):

And the JavaScript code:

```
  var preEl ;
  var orgBColor;
  var orgTColor;
  function HighLightTR(el, backColor,textColor){
  if(typeof(preEl)!='undefined') {
     preEl.bgColor=orgBColor;
     try{ChangeTextColor(preEl,orgTColor);}catch(e){;}
  }
   orgBColor = el.bgColor;
   orgTColor = el.style.color;
   el.bgColor=backColor;

    try{ChangeTextColor(el,textColor);}catch(e){;}
    preEl = el;

    addRowHandlers();
  }

  function ChangeTextColor(a_obj,a_color){  ;
     for (i=0;i<a_obj.cells.length;i++)
      a_obj.cells(i).style.color=a_color;
  }

  function addRowHandlers() {
    var table = document.getElementById("table-organizaciones");
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      var currentRow = table.rows[i];
      var createClickHandler = function(row) {
            return function() { 
              var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
              var id = cell.innerHTML;
              alert("id:" + id);
              document.getElementById('id_org').value = id;
            };
       };

    currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
  }
 }
```

The html:

```
<table id="table-organizaciones">

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="col-xs-4">Nombre</th>
          <th class="col-xs-4">Razon social</th>
          <th class="col-xs-4">Pais</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr onClick="HighLightTR(this,'#c9cc99','cc3333');">            
          <td class="col-xs-4">Lo que sea</td>
          <td class="col-xs-4">Lo que sea </td>
          <td class="col-xs-4">Colombia</td>
          <td>maybe</td>   
        </tr>
        <tr onClick="HighLightTR(this,'#c9cc99','cc3333');">            
          <td class="col-xs-4">Lo que sea</td>
          <td class="col-xs-4">Lo que sea </td>
          <td class="col-xs-4">Colombia</td>
          <td>no</td>   
        </tr>
        <tr onClick="HighLightTR(this,'#c9cc99','cc3333');">            
          <td class="col-xs-4">Lo que sea</td>
          <td class="col-xs-4">Lo que sea </td>
          <td class="col-xs-4">Colombia</td>
          <td>yes</td>   
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <input name="id" id="id_org" value="id">
```

Answer (score 1):

**This is much simpler than you have made it.** Your code used the very old syntax of inline HTML event handling attributes (`onclick=...`), which shouldn't be used for several reasons:

- As your code showed, there was a great deal of duplicated code.
- HTML and JavaScript appear within a single line of code (this is
  called "spaghetti code") and is more difficult to read and debug.
- When you use event handling attributes (`onclick`, etc.), anonymous
  global wrapper functions get created around your code and these
  functions interfere with the "normal" functionality of the code.
- This technique doesn't follow **[modern web standards for event
  handling](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20131105/#methods-1)**.

Much of your code was devoted to setting up handlers and maintaining them. This wasn't necessary and was the reason why things weren't happening when you wanted them to. All the functions that returned other functions was completely unnecessary.

Since all highlighted rows should look the same, it makes much more sense to set up a CSS class that defines that look and simply apply that class to the selected row and remove it from all others when a row gets clicked.

Also, classes can be added to any row that "could" be clicked and this makes finding them in JavaScript and looping over them so much more simple.

By separating the content (HTML), the formatting (CSS) and the behavior (JavaScript), your code is much cleaner. It's easier to read and it's easier to modify down the road because there is so much less duplication and much less code overall. This is the modern approach to building for the web called "Progressive Enhancement".

You also had some `try/catch` code that is not needed. `try/catch` should only be used when the code may crash due to circumstances outside of the developer's control (i.e. network outages). Since you can control what element(s) your code is working with, then there is no reason for this.

See the inline comments for descriptions of what the code does each step of the way and look in the HTML and CSS for comments as well.

```js
// When the document's elements have been loaded...
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

  // First, get references to the elelements your script needs
  
  // All clickable rows have been given a class of "row" in the HTML
  var theRows = document.querySelectorAll(".row");
  var input = document.getElementById("id_org");

  // Set up the click event handlers in JavaScript using the modern, 
  // standard approach (not in HTML). We'll loop over all the rows
  // that have been designated as a clickable row in the HTML with the
  // "row" class.
  for(var i = 0; i < theRows.length; ++i){
    // As we encounter each row, we register a click event handling function
    // that should be invoked (highlightRow). That's it - nothing else needed!
    theRows[i].addEventListener("click", highlightRow);
  }
 
  function highlightRow(){
    // Remove highlight from all rows by looping over them
    for(var i = 0; i < theRows.length; ++i){
      theRows[i].classList.remove("highlight");;
    }
    
    // Now, add highlight to the selected row
    this.classList.add("highlight");
    
    // Call the dedicated function that updates the input field and
    // pass it a reference to the currently clicked row (this).
    updateValue(this);
  }

  function updateValue(row){
    // Get the cells in the row
    var cells = row.querySelectorAll("td");
    
    // Now, get the text from the 4th cell and put it into the text box
    input.value = cells[3].textContent;  
  }

});
```

```css
/* Make a class for all rows to use when they are supposed to be highlighted: */
.highlight {
  background-color:#c9cc99;
  color:#c33;
}
```

```html
<table id="table-organizaciones">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col-xs-4">Nombre</th>
      <th class="col-xs-4">Razon social</th>
      <th class="col-xs-4">Pais</th>
      <th></th> <!-- All rows need the same amount of cells! -->
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- Each row that is clickable has been given a class 
         called "row". This is what JavaScript will use to find them. 
         Also, notice that the onclick=". . . " code that every row
         had has been removed. This is handled once in JavaScript. -->
    <tr class="row">            
      <td class="col-xs-4">Lo que sea</td>
      <td class="col-xs-4">Lo que sea</td>
      <td class="col-xs-4">Colombia</td>
      <td>maybe</td>   
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">            
      <td class="col-xs-4">Lo que sea</td>
      <td class="col-xs-4">Lo que sea</td>
      <td class="col-xs-4">Colombia</td>
      <td>no</td>   
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">            
      <td class="col-xs-4">Lo que sea</td>
      <td class="col-xs-4">Lo que sea</td>
      <td class="col-xs-4">Colombia</td>
      <td>yes</td>   
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input name="id" id="id_org" value="id">
```

Comment: Very elaborated post indeed. I will retract my own answer in favor of this one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that HighLightTR function is set in the HTML elements and when you run addRowHandlers you override the event in these elements. So in the first time you click the events are still there, and you get the line hightlight. But after the hightlight you run a addRowHandlers and override the events so you don't get the rest of the hightlights.

Solution: move the call to HighLightTR to createClickHandler, then run addRowHandlers on form load. Here:

```
var preEl;
var orgBColor;
var orgTColor;

function HighLightTR(el, backColor, textColor) {
    if (typeof (preEl) != 'undefined') {
        preEl.bgColor = orgBColor;
        try {
            ChangeTextColor(preEl, 'black');
        } catch (e) {;
        }
    }
    orgBColor = el.bgColor;
    el.bgColor = backColor;

    try {
        ChangeTextColor(el, textColor);
    } catch (e) {;
    }
    preEl = el;

}

function ChangeTextColor(a_obj, a_color) {;
    for (i = 0; i < a_obj.cells.length; i++) {
        a_obj.cells[i].style['color'] = a_color;
    }
}

function addRowHandlers() {
    var table = document.getElementById("table-organizaciones");
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var currentRow = table.rows[i];
        var createClickHandler =
            function (row) {
                return function () {
                    var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[3];
                    var id = cell.innerHTML;
                    //alert("id:" + id);
                    document.getElementById('id_org').value = id;
                    HighLightTR(row, '#c9cc99', '#cc3333');
                };
            };

        currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
    }
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<table id="table-organizaciones">

          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="col-xs-4">Nombre</th><th class="col-xs-4">Razon social</th><th class="col-xs-4">Pais</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>            
              <td class="col-xs-4">Lo que sea</td><td class="col-xs-4">Lo que sea </td><td class="col-xs-4">Colombia</td><td>maybe</td>   
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="col-xs-4">Lo que sea</td><td class="col-xs-4">Lo que sea </td><td class="col-xs-4">Colombia</td><td>no</td>   
            </tr>
            <tr >            
              <td class="col-xs-4">Lo que sea</td><td class="col-xs-4">Lo que sea </td><td class="col-xs-4">Colombia</td><td>yes</td>   
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <input name="id" id="id_org" value="id">
<script>
    addRowHandlers();
</script>
```

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/n32d72ve/17/

Comment: Your solution does not change the text color and still includes the gobs and gobs of unnecessary code.

Comment: Well... have you checked the JSFiddle ? it does change the color. Also, I tried to correct only the necessary, because if it did this code like that, this show he's learning, so I tought a solution for his specific problem would be better than a total rewrite that he has to re-understand from the beggining.

Comment: Have *you* checked the fiddle? The **text** color does not change.

Comment: Are we talking about the same fiddle ? I'm looking at https://jsfiddle.net/n32d72ve/11/ and I double checked it. It's working. What browser/SO are you using ? I tested it in Firefox and Chrome. I'm on Linux so I can't test IE.

Comment: Or you mean the front text color, not the background color ?

Comment: Right, that's why both of my comments explicitly said "text" and the last one even bolded **text**.

Comment: Well I didn't think it was much relevant, because the main problem with his code was the overwritting of the event handlers. But if you think is is relevant... here: changed it to change the front text color. Don't think this contributed much though.

Comment: With respect, it's all relevant. Especially since there is so much code in the question that attempts to set the color. Solving just one issue, while not doing anything about all the unnecessary and contradictory code isn't a good way to answer. The OP is clearly learning incorrect ways of doing things, so patching one thing and leaving the rest is a dis-service to the OP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136489/discussion-between-nelson-teixeira-and-scott-marcus).

Answer (score -1):

Instead of inserting or alternating a style try the following:
https://jsfiddle.net/yj6jmmgo/

1. Create a css with a `.selected {background-color: green;}`
2. Toggle your class withing JS

   ```
   var lastElm;
   var inputElm = document.getElementById("input");
   window.highlight = function(elm) {
     if(lastElm) lastElm.classList.remove("selected");
     elm.classList.add("selected");
     lastElm = elm;
     inputElm.value = elm.children[0].innerText;
   }
   ```

Comment: While `innerText` is widely supported, it's not standard. `textContent` should be used instead.

Comment: Your fiddle does nothing and includes invalid HTML syntax on the `<input>`